# Which is the best php opensource e-commerce for handle 5 million prducts import daily?

Tags: php, magento, oscommerce, e-commerce

I am going to develop a B2B e-commerce site which contains 5 million products and all products will update from distributor daily.I am confusing which open source i have to use I tried magento but it importing very slowly.I am ready to spent money for highly configured server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definite answer for you since I find myself in a similar situation, but don't use Magento.

It's even expensive when it's free. It's slow and bloat, when customized, upgrades are next to impossible. The API is notoriously slow. Also, unless you want to start a shopping club, there's little to gain from the Enterprise version either.

I'd look into [Veyton](https://www.xtcommerce-shop.com/) or [OXID](http://www.oxid-esales.com/) right now. Veyton is a brand-new shop system, pretty extensible and pleasant to work with. OXID is one of the newer players in the ecommerce scene, though they don't seem to get as much press as Magento.

Last but not least - let me asure you - there's nothing wrong with using osCommerce. We have a fork in house which has a lot of functionality added (e.g. multishop, templates, sync to CRM etc.) and it's been running very well for us. I haven't checked out the new releases lately but they have come a long way. :)

Comment: Thanks Till.Now osCommerce is running well for me.

Answer (score 0):

For free? I doubt you'll find the perfect solution for free. If you're ready to 'spend money' look into Magento Enterprise edition.

Comment: But i imported 50,000 products in oscommerce with in a minute.But its code is horrible and need to change many lines of code for customization.

Answer (score 0):

Magento's default import tool (DataFlow) is quite slow. For 5 million products I would rather recommend a custom optimized importer specific for your data format and working low-level (Resource Models level). You can also try http://www.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/ and discuss with the author some ways of optimizing it. However usually only a small subset of such product import is really changed - does you distributor mark the rows that were really updated? By filtering them you will be able to speed up the process significantly.

Comment: Thank you macki. I already started the project with oscommerce and now its going good.

Comment: There is a big difference between 50k products that you imported already and 5mln that you want to import. I would suggest first evaluating how the site works with 5mln products.